# htaccess for Symfony on Shared Hosting

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, symfony1, url-rewriting

Im trying to setup a local environment that resembles shared hosting. I have copied the entire project into the htdocs directory, and thus the application does not start by default in the web directory.

For this I found these 2 references:
http://oldforum.symfony-project.org/index.php/m/98117/
http://www.teamlalala.com/blog/2010/05/02/how-to-handle-symfony-on-shared-hosting/

But I have 2 doubts:
1. The .htaccess mentioned in the posts is to be added inside the WEB folder, or in the ROOT folder
2. If added to the ROOT folder, should we remove the default .HTACCESS in WEB?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should place `.htaccess` file in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder. By default in symfony it is `sf_project_dir/web`.