# How to move properly Symfony 2.1 project from localhost to web service provider (1and1)

Tags: webserver, symfony-2.1, move

The first important thing is I'm new user of Symfony 2.1, so some sort of this I do not now yet. So this post could be good example to others users of Symfony 2.

Back to main question. I'm trying to export my Symfony project (whole project) to `1and1` web server. I have made some research how to do it, but all methods fail in my case.

What I've done:

1. I moved all project files to the server.
2. Prepared a subdomain ([adress](http://grawero.egel.pl)), point on `/web` folder and confirure `.htaccess` file from tutorial of [1and1 mod_rewrite issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8681959/1and1-mod-rewrite-issues) and [symfony2 rewrite rules .htaccess app.php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11149526/symfony2-rewrite-rules-htaccess-app-php).

This is my `.htaccess` file in `/web` folder

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymlinks
    RewriteEngine On
    Options -MultiViews

    # Explicitly disable rewriting for front controllers
    RewriteRule ^app_dev.php - [L]
    RewriteRule ^app.php - [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

    # Change below before deploying to production
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php [QSA,L]
    #RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app_dev.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

I thought it should worked, but no still shows `Internal Server Error 500`

`Notice:` While I'm reading this post I found this [article of htaccess in Symfony](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5799050/htaccess-for-symfony-on-shared-hosting) but it's not mentioning that .htaccess file should be moved or just copy to root.

Please, explain step by step what to do, what steps are very important to do it properly, or where I did something wrong?

Comment: I've never moved sf2 projects on 1n1, but sooner or later I will. Have you called the check.php file first?

Answer (score 0):

1. Use the `check.php` because there is 77% possibility that you're missing some php module.
2. Check the files perrmisions in `app/logs` `app/cache`
3. Next time configure some deploy script and after the deploy use composer to install vendors
   It will give you what's missing.

**Reqired:**

- PHP needs to be a minimum version of PHP 5.3.3
- JSON needs to be enabled
- ctype needs to be enabled
- Your PHP.ini needs to have the date.timezone setting

**Optional:**

- You need to have the PHP-XML module installed
- You need to have at least version 2.6.21 of libxml
- PHP tokenizer needs to be enabled
- mbstring functions need to be enabled
- iconv needs to be enabled
- POSIX needs to be enabled (only on *nix)
- Intl needs to be installed with ICU 4+
- APC 3.0.17+ (or another opcode cache needs to be installed)
- PHP.ini recommended settings

  - short_open_tag = Off
  - magic_quotes_gpc = Off
  - register_globals = Off
  - session.autostart = Off

Comment: Thank you Max for your post. I think that my check.php file looks correct, so another question needs to be asked... What modules of PHP Symfony needs obligatory to proper work?

Comment: I've added the required and optional things to run the sf2.1